# How to bound a value in a function in r

Tags: r, function, bounds

I have this function to maximize:

```
funcToOpt <- function (theta1,theta2,theta3)
{
  inner <- rowSums((wb + (theta1*X1+theta2*X2+theta3*X3) / Nt) * r)  
  innerU <- u(inner, gamma)                                     # u() is another function 

  return (sum(innerU) / T)
}

fbb <- function(x) funcToOpt(x[1],x[2],x[3])
max <- optim(c(0,0,0),fbb,control=list(fnscale=-1))
```

Where: `wb,X1,X2,X3,r` are `TxN` matrices and `Nt` a vector with length of `N`

I wanna just that

```
(wb + (theta1*X1+theta2*X2+theta3*X3) / Nt)
```

can't assume `negative` values.

Is there someone who can help me? Thanks!

Comment: use `pmin` or `pmax`, they'll do the bounding you're after

Comment: should I put  "pmin" inside the optim() function? Where exactly?

Comment: You actually want `pmax`, and `pmax(wb + ((theta1*X1+theta2*X2+theta3*X3) / Nt),0)`

Comment: Assuming you want 0 in the case of negative values, of course

Comment: If i try                                                                                                 funcToOpt <- function (theta1,theta2,theta3)
{
  wi=wb + (theta1*X1+theta2*X2+theta3*X3) / Nt
  inner <- rowSums((pmax(wi,0)) * r,na.rm = TRUE)  
  innerU <- u(inner, gamma)
   
  return (sum(innerU, na.rm=TRUE) / T)
}                                                                                                                           it still give back negative values for wi found the thetas

Comment: are you sure r is positive? `pmax(wi,0)` shouldn't ever give negatives

Comment: r is both negative and positive, but it shouldn't be a problem cause 0*(negative number) still give 0. Right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120886/discussion-between-matteo-guidarini-and-shape).

Comment: Bounds can sometimes create discontinuities and cause problems for optimizers. An alternative is to transform the linear term with an exponential function where the result will always be positive.

Comment: For yet another alternative look up "Lagrange multipliers with inequality constraints"